# Laravel 5.3 Composer Update Kernel Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've recently started a new project with Laravel 5.3, but when I run #composer update, it updates all packages and in the end brings this weird error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$schedule' (T_VARIABLE) in /path/to/laravel/project/app/Console/Kernel.php on line 40

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the contents of the schedule function in app/Console/Kernel.php? There seems to be a syntax error.

Comment: There is a syntax error on like 40, you've missed a semi colon or added a character where it shouldn't be.